# Who/What am I by SC #6

Tags: riddle, word

Split me into 3, and you will feel like iron,

But you see I am much stronger than it.

Split me into 6, and you will feel like aluminium,

But you see I can't be softened as easily as it.

I stand next to a precious golden treasure,

But I am still much more valuable than it.

What/Who am I?

Comment: this is really pathetic. again a downvoted question. REASON? is it unclear? is it broad? what? that's it I am done with this

Comment: I do downvotes as well, but it is rare and I give explanation to the user why I downvoted so he/she can improve. I don't see anything wrong here to get a downvote, other than random hate.

Comment: Indeed! Those aren't drive-bys. Often I even feel obligated to explain an upvote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is

> Platinum

**Explanation**

> One thing to keep in mind is that Atomic number of platinum is 78

Split me into 3, and you will feel like iron,

> 78/3 = 26. And 26 is the atomic number of Iron.

But you see I am much more stronger than it.

> Yes. Bulk Modulus of platinum is 230 GPa while of the iron is 170 GPa

Split me into 6, and you will feel like alluminium,

> 78/6 = 13. And atomic number of aluminium is 13

But you see I can't be softened as easy as it.

> Aluminium is more malleable than platinum

I stand next to a precious golden treasure,

> In [periodic table](http://www.ptable.com/), Platinum is right next to Gold which have atomic number 79

But I am still much more valuable than it.

> Yes, I think we all know that.

Comment: well done mate. I see you like chemistry ^^

Comment: Nice use of the B word before the M word. Learn something new every day, on a good day!

Comment: @SirSC [Maybe](http://cdn.meme.am/instances/55370735.jpg)